# Вывести надпись по центру

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Столкнулся с проблемой. Я не знаю как определенную надпись сделать по центру сайта.

HTML код:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Hello!</title>
  <style>
   body{
   background: url(one.jpg) no-repeat;
     -moz-background-size: 100%; /* Firefox 3.6+ */
     -webkit-background-size: 100%; /* Safari 3.1+ ? Chrome 4.0+ */
     -o-background-size: 100%; /* Opera 9.6+ */
     background-size: 100%; /* ??????????? ???????? */
    }
  </style> 
  </head>
   <p>...</p>
  <body>
   <div class="logo">
     <font>DABLYA</font>
     <font style="color: #a0a5db">.ARCHOST.RU</font>
   </div>   
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Начинающему разработчику стоит незамедлительно выкинуть HTML 4.01 вместе с тегом font и взяться за изучение современных HTML5 и CSS3

Comment: по ценру - это по вертикали или по горизонтали?

Comment: @andreymal тогда поинтересуюсь у вас сразу. С чего лучше начать создание сайтов на HTML5 и CSS3?

Comment: Для начинающего веб-разработчика (который еще и документацию читать не любит) советую разобраться с [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/)

Comment: @toxxxa по центру. И по вертикали и по горизонтали!

Comment: А можете пожалуйста подробно об этом рассказать? Что именно это прога дает? 
я просто на сайт зашел, но особо не понял

Comment: @АндрейЮданов с любого современного учебника, в котором не будет ни слова ни про HTML 4.01, ни про font :) А тот источник, откуда вы узнали про font, выбросьте

Comment: Во-первых, не является ответом на вопрос, во-вторых, bootstrap не отменяет необходимости знать основы HTML и CSS, в-третьих, bootstrap отвратителен

Comment: @andreymal тогда помогите найти хорошую книгу, в которой можно изучить то, что надо для создания сайта

Comment: дополню сообщение сверху: "пожалуйста"

Answer (score 4):

В CSS

```
.logo {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Попробовал. Не работает.

Comment: @АндрейЮданов, а можете добавить стили .logo и дочерних элементов в вопрос?

Comment: такс. я слишком тупой, чтобы понять это, честно.

Comment: @АндрейЮданов, у `.logo` есть свои стили? Если нету и всё так, как у вас в вопросе, то всё должно работать.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать ячейку от таблицы во всю ширину и высоту или как удобно, установить толщину 0 px и выравнить код по центру в ячейке на css(это можно найти в интернете, там куча примеров) (выравнить по высоте по центру можно только в таблице)